# cylinder simulation on top of each other in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I created 2 cylinders and put one on top of the other. Then I clicked to simulate physics and on each cylinder I added the following image blueprint, added a 50-point rotation on the z axis of each cylinder in opposite directions.

It turns out that in the simulation, when I perform, the cylinders rotate in one direction and move on the ground in the other direction. If it turns clockwise it moves left, and vice versa, and should be the other way around.

Can anyone help me solve this? It's for both cylinders to work together and I see how their simulation is accelerating with a constant rotation, but that's not what happens

[image: Blueprint]

[image: Scene]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate physics you should be applying forces to the cylinders using *Add Torque in Radians* or *Add Torque in Degrees* rather than modifying the rotation directly.

Alternatively, if you want to precisely control the cylinders, do not simulate physics. Instead, disable *Simulate Physics* and animate the rotation and position of the cylinders directly as you are.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.